# Unity's Perlin Noise

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a terrain editor software that can be used by people to modify our game.
I am creating the application in Visual Studio.
When generating terrainmaps we use PerlinNoise.
In the game we use:

```
for (int y = 0; y < pointCount; y++)
   valuePointer[y] += Mathf.PerlinNoise((float)(start + delta * y) * width, 0) * height;
}
```

But you can't use Unity's math liberary outside unity's environment.
Since they depend on some C++ scripts that Mono would implement or something like that.
*My question is: What method/liberary is best to use so we can use it in the Unity project and in the Visual Studio project?*
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a standalone high performance math lib, just look this https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Unity.Mathematics